# Decode Unicode chars

Tags: string, go, unicode, decode

I am using Stackoverflow API to fetch some data but the response contains Unicode and some other encodings which I am unable to decode. Here's one sample text:

```
you can use numpy \u0026#39;\u0026#39;\u0026#39;
python 
import numpy as np 
np.random.random((pN,C,K))\u0026#39;\u0026#39;\u0026#39;
```

What's the best way to decode this response in Go?

The sample text is a Python answer I received as response from Stackoverflow API.

Comment: Is this a question about Python or Go? It appears your question tags are wrong.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo this is Golang question. The text response is an answer in python.

Comment: @MuffinTop I am doing ```json.Unmarshal(body)``` for the response I am getting from ```http.Get(url)```

Comment: The encoding/json package decodes `\u0026` to `&` as expected.  Edit the question to show your actual code and how you print the text.

Comment: You seem confused about what Unicode is. "Normal" text is Unicode. The text you're reading now is Unicode. The text in your question is _escape sequences_, which may or may not be represented in Unicode, or represent Unicode codepoints when unescaped.

Answer (score 2):

Several layers of encoding seem to be in place here:

1. first, the `\u0026` could be a `&` character
2. this gives `&#39;` which seems to be an XML character literal for `'`
3. the resulting `'''` seems to mark up the enclosed text to be taken literally including the line breaks. It is also possible that the `python` indicates the language for syntax highlighting of the enclosed text.